# For next Loop (beginner)

Tags: excel, vba

[image: for next]

I want to copy gray cells to rows but only last column gray cell copied.

Comment: All cells are copied, but each copy overwrites the previous copy. Execute this code by repeatedly pressing F8 and observe the changes.

Comment: This would be a good time to learn that you should not post images of code, no matter how small the code segment is.

Answer (score 4):

There's no need for nested loops

```
Sub Test()
Dim r As Integer, c As Integer

r = 3
For c = 3 To 21 Step 3
    Cells(r, 1) = Cells(1, c)
    r = r + 1
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice one Yasser

Answer (score 2):

You are so close :)

```
Option Explicit

Sub istebu()

Dim x As Long
Dim i As Long

For i = 3 To 10 'Loop in row from 3 to 10
    For x = 3 To 21 Step 3 'Loop header row, from 3 to 21, jump 3
        Cells(i, 1) = Cells(1, x) 'Copy values.
        i = i + 1 'Add one row each time, so we don't overwrite previously row
    Next x
Next i
End Sub
```

---

Alternative:

It could be shortened as we don't need to loop through the rows. We only need to add them. So we set `i` to the start row where we should paste our data.

```
Sub istebu()

Dim x As Long
Dim i As Long

i = 3 'Set first row number you want to loop from.

For x = 3 To 21 Step 3 'Loop header row, from 3 to 21, jump 3
        Cells(i, 1) = Cells(1, x) 'Copy values.
        i = i + 1 'Add one row each time, so we don't overwrite previously row
Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative to loops altogether.

```
Range("C1,F1,I1,L1,O1,R1,U1").Copy
Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
```

But if you're really into loops, use one to build a union.

```
dim i as long, rng as range

for 3 to 21 step 3
    if rng is nothing then
        set rng = cells(1, i)
    else
        set rng = union(rng, cells(1, i))
    end if
next i

rng.Copy
Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
```